# How to find absolute extrema?

Tags: calculus

$f(x) = \sqrt{2}\cos x-1$

So far, I have $f^{\prime}(x) = - \sqrt{2}\sin x = 0$.

What are the next steps?

Comment: For which values of $x$ does $\sin(x)=0$?

Comment: Since cosine is a bounded function,  $ \ f(x) \ $ is also bounded (it has largest and smallest values).  If you don't have an interval specified for this, there are going to be _an infinite number_ of absolute extrema (which you don't even need calculus to determine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivative is the following (as you showed):

$$f'(x)=-\sqrt2\sin x$$

Setting equal to zero:

$$-\sqrt2\sin x=0$$

Dividing by $-\sqrt2$:

$$\sin x=0$$

$$x=0,\;  \pi, \;2\pi... $$

$$(\text i.e. x=n\pi\;|\;n\in\Bbb Z)$$